# how loop XMLStreamReader using lambda

Tags: lambda, java-8

This is more a question for learning purpose than really a serious need. 
I am using code below to check if a xml file is valid. I am not worring about schema validation here.
I know XMLStreamReader is an interface but I tried to find some implemention that allow me to do something close to:

```
        Stream<String> s = reader.getText();
        s.forEach(System.out::println);
```

//my complete code without lambda

```
public interface CheckXml {

default boolean readFile(String f) throws IOException {
    Boolean result = false;
    FileInputStream inputStream = null;

    try {
        XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();

        inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
        XMLStreamReader reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);

        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            reader.next();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }

    }
    return result;
}
```

//edited

```
import com.iread.CheckXml;

public class CheckXmlFiles implements CheckXml {
}

//...
@Test
public void testXmlValidation() throws IOException {
    CheckXml c = new CheckXmlFiles(); 
    assertTrue("For simplicity it is expected 'true'", c.readFile("C:\\_pocs\\temp\\demo.xml"));
}
```

Comment: Your "complete code without lambda" doesn't look complete to me. It should at least contain the code that obtains the `String`s you wish to put in that `Stream<String>`.

Comment: Create an `Iterator<Something>`, where the `Something` is what you want to get out during the `while` - for example `XMLElement` or `Person`. Wrap that `Iterator` in a `Spliterator`. Create a `Stream` from the `Spliterator`.

Comment: @Eran honestly I don't know what it matter in this question but here you are; I added to my question

Comment: @BoristheSpider, can you elaborate a bit more your idea? As far as I know, Spliterator are aimed to be used when we want to split a large file in some reasonable smaller virtual files we wnat to read in parallel (multithread approach). By large file, I mean large enough to be reasonable approach in memory (not a real big file). On top of that, in my case, I am reading the stream just because I want to be sure the xml is properly formed. It can be any xml so I can't use a Pojo like Person. I guess XMLElement will be suitable to my case but how to accomplish it with Iterator/Spliterator?:

Comment: Not sure where you got any of that information; but it's completely incorrect. Read up on the `Stream` API.

Comment: Also; can't you just use `Validator` API to validate your XML. Why are you doing this?

Comment: @BoristheSpider, (1) according to https://blog.logentries.com/2015/10/java-8-introduction-to-parallelism-and-spliterator/ "The Spliterator can ‘split’ the Collection, partitioning off some of its elements as another Spliterator". (2) based on personal experience, we only use Validator API to validate a xml file against XSD. Certainly, this isn't my case since I want to validate any xml submitted (only validate if it is well formed). BTW, if Spliterator can be used to allow me code with lambda the above mentioned piece, can you give more tricks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert an `XmlStreamReader` to a stream and then use it. It requires for you to create an iterator that calls the `hasNext` and `next` methods for example.

There are some headaches on the way to an implementation: XmlStreamReader throws checked exceptions and that will force you to create some extra exception handling code that will bloat the code.

Also note that the stream underlying to the `XmlStreamReader` has to be closed inside the iterator. If you close it outside, you will be facing some stream closed exceptions. You cannot use `try with resources` either in this scenario.

I have tried to create a simple stream and a simple test which counts the number of elements available in an XML file.

Here is some toy code to demonstrate how you eventually could do it:

```
public class XMLStreamReaderStream {

    public static Stream<Integer> fromFile(File f) throws IOException, XMLStreamException {
        XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        Reader inputStream;
        inputStream = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f), "UTF-8");
        XMLStreamReader reader = factory.createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);

        Iterator<Integer> iterator = new Iterator<>() {
            public Integer next() {
                try {
                    return reader.next();
                } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }

            public boolean hasNext() {
                try {
                    boolean hasNext = reader.hasNext();
                    if (!hasNext) {
                        reader.close(); // close the stream here
                    }
                    return hasNext;
                } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super Integer> action) {
                while (hasNext()) {
                    action.accept(next());
                }
            }
        };

        return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, Spliterator.ORDERED), false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, XMLStreamException {
        File sampleXml = new File("stackoverflow1.xml");
        LinkedHashMap<Integer, Long> xmlStats = fromFile(sampleXml).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
        Map<String, Long> readableMap = xmlStats.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> {
            Optional<Field> opt = Stream.of(XMLStreamConstants.class.getDeclaredFields()).filter(f -> {
                try {
                    return e.getKey().equals(f.get(null));
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
                    return false;
                }
            }).findFirst();
            return opt.map(s -> s.toString().replaceAll(".+\\.", "")).orElseGet(() -> Integer.toString(e.getKey()));
        }, Map.Entry::getValue));
        System.out.println(readableMap);
    }
}
```

This code will count the types of tags found in the XML file and prints it out to the console:

```
{START_ELEMENT=22, END_DOCUMENT=1, END_ELEMENT=22, CHARACTERS=27}
```